# How to use a MySQL query on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

For my classes, I need to insert this query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE id=14;
ALTER TABLE tmp DROP id; 
INSERT INTO tracks SELECT 0,tmp.* FROM tmp;
DROP TABLE tmp;
UPDATE comments SET tid = (SELECT id FROM tracks ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1), time=time WHERE tid = 14;
UPDATE likes SET track = (SELECT id FROM tracks ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1), time=time WHERE track=14;
DELETE FROM tracks WHERE id = 14;
```

inside my PHP code:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("...");
```

The problem is that `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` is not working. What's the exact syntax to execute this query?

Comment: What does not working mean; provide the exact error message you're getting back

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this as easily as you want - you can't pass multiple queries into the same database call, unless you're using `mysqli_multi_query`

Comment: @andrewsi as usual! Could you please share something?

Comment: *"sublime text doesn't highlight it"* - what does sublime have to do with SQL?

Comment: again, what does this have to so with sublime? edit: you deleted your comment/reply to me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- if you read the question, I'm trying to use PHP for execute a MySQL query...so I'm inside a PHP file

Comment: the only PHP'ish code I see, is `$stmt = $this->db->prepare("...");` where's the rest of it and the real code you're using in order to perform all those queries?

Comment: @Fred-ii- it doesn't make sense to me O_o

Comment: you and me both; *grab an oar* ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only execute a single query at a time...

```
// stick your queries in a string...
$queries = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE id=14;
ALTER TABLE tmp DROP id; 
INSERT INTO tracks SELECT 0,tmp.* FROM tmp;
DROP TABLE tmp;
UPDATE comments SET tid = (SELECT id FROM tracks ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1), time=time WHERE tid = 14;
UPDATE likes SET track = (SELECT id FROM tracks ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1), time=time WHERE track=14;
DELETE FROM tracks WHERE id = 14;";

// break them up into multiple seperate queries...
$qs = explode(";",$queries);

// execute each one
foreach($qs as $sql){
    $stmt = $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Inside PHP can I use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`? I'm asking because Sublime text 2 doesn't highlight it

Comment: he is using it with PDO

Comment: @Simone - It doesn't matter whether you're using PHP or not, what matter's is whether or not the user you're connecting with has permissions to create a table. If so, then yes.

Comment: @SatenderK - Yeah, what's your point?

Comment: @Adelphia I am saying here it is prepared statement not mysql_query, he can use mysqli_multi_query()

Comment: @Simone: It's just a SQL query, your IDE's syntax highlighting is a different issue.

Comment: @SatenderK The code I've posted is PDO, you don't need to use prepare() unless you've actually got variables to bind. For this, query() works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Change it like as below :

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp LIKE tracks;
 INSERT INTO tmp SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE id=14;
```

Comment: my problem is in PHP not in MySQL...in PHP the command CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE doesn't work.

Comment: Which extension you are using dude

Comment: According to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html), `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE id=14;` is valid SQL.

Comment: It is correct but if you will create table like that then indexes will not be created